# Print rows of triangle if a user specifies (more than 0)

Tags: java, loops

I want the code to do this:
If I enter '5' it would print 5 triangle rows like this:

```
+

++

+++

++++ 

+++++
```

I also want to inverse it afterwards so that it looks like so:

```
+++++ 

++++ 

+++ 

++ 

+
```

This is my attempt:

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testo1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Rows = 0;
        //
        while(Rows<=0){
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want in your triangle, more than 0?: ");
        Rows = input.nextInt();
        }while(Rows>=0){
        //Honestly, I don't know what to do here or the logic to implement. 
        }

    }
}
```

I commented the part in the while loop where I got lost. I want this in a while-loop nest. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem. Have you tried to solve this by yourself?

Comment: If you have no idea what do to, this is the wrong place to visit. Come back with a specific question and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it with nested-loops.

Take a look at this code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int Rows = 0;
while (Rows <= 0) { // Keep asking the user if they enter something less than zero
    System.out.print("How many rows do you want in your triangle, more than 0?: ");
    Rows = input.nextInt(); 
    }

// If you got out of the while loop, that means you got a positive row number

for (int i = 1; i <= Rows; i++) { // number of lines
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) // number of stars at each line
        System.out.print("*"); // printing stars
    System.out.print("\n"); // line break
    }
```

For the inverse, you just change the loops to:

```
for (int i = Rows; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Oooh that makes sense. Looks very efficient too. I'll have to incorporate this type of logic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve any pattern just with the help of looping and by focusing
that how they actually work and print. Giving an example of a normal triangle printing:-

```
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
      int n=scn.nextInt();
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
       for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)

       {
        if((i+j)>n)
        {
        System.out.print("#");
        }
        else
        {
         System.out.print(" ");
        }

       }
       System.out.println();

      }

The output would be:-

    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Same way, you can make changes and produce different output. For example, change # with empty string, and you'll get the reversing order.

```
#####
#### 
###  
##   
#
```

Another pattern you can make is:-

```
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n=scn.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                for(int j=i+1;j>0;j--){
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            }

This will output as:-

*
**
***
****
*****
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be taking a look at all of these lines of java-codes and trying to incorporate it. Means a lot, I appreciate it!